# How to check time format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, time, format

I need to check that my string is in a format of time **`HH24:MI:SS`**.

I made a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_time(myStr VARCHAR2) RETURN INT IS
   p_temp DATE;
BEGIN
     p_temp := TO_DATE(myStr, 'HH24:MI:SS');    
   RETURN 1;
 EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN RETURN 0;
END;
```

But the `TO_DATE()` not failing when getting number between **0** and **23**;
I need the string to be in the exact format of **`HH24:MI:SS`** with the colon.

I looking for a solution that uses the Oracle Date/Time formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent Oracle from apply lax rules to the conversion then you can add [the 'FX' format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

```
p_temp := TO_DATE(myStr, 'FXHH24:MI:SS');
```

On recent versions of Oracle you don't need your own function, you can use [`validate_conversion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html), which will give you the same 0/1 result:

```
validate_conversion('<your_string>' as date, 'FXHH24:MI:SS')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/68UqtXPg) with some sample valid and invalid values.